# Is it possible to fix this "LimitExceededException" in cognito?

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, limit, aws-amplify

I tried to update email in my react-native project.
I called this api.

```
 Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, newAttribute)
```

It will send the verify code(123456) with the user's email.

I thought its limitation will be over after 10 or 30 mins.
But not, it was lasting...
So I had to check the logs.
Here, it is.

```
{
"code": "LimitExceededException",
"message": "Exceeded daily email limit for the operation or the account. If a higher limit is required, please configure your user pool to use your own Amazon SES configuration for sending email.",
"name": "LimitExceededException"
}
```

Any idea to avoid this?

Thanks.

Comment: Here I share official blog for this. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-sending-rate-quota-exceeded/

Comment: Maybe you can find the answer you want in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65450298/22414047)

Answer (score 0):

I had to check the error message more carefully.
It means I have used all emails, and the aws has the limitation number of emails that can be sent,

In my case, the status of my aws account is still in sandbox.
Unfortunately, the limit number was 200, for the sandbox.
For the real one, it is 20000.

I had to wait and work again.

Comment: Also, we can solve this by upgrading the membership plan from the sandbox to premium